# VB.NET grab stored procedure code

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am wondering if there is a way to grab the stored procedure code from a SQL Server 2008 R2?

For example, if I had the following code to create this stored procedure:

```
USE AdventureWorks;  
GO  
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspGetEmployeesTest2   
    @LastName nvarchar(50),   
    @FirstName nvarchar(50)   
AS   

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Department  
    FROM HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory  
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName  
    AND EndDate IS NULL;  
GO
```

Is there a way I can write a SQL statement to get the text everything between `'SET NO COUNT ON' to 'IS NULL'`?

Comment: Stored procedures are stored in a table.  I would assume that you could get the SQL code from that table.  You should be able to find out if that's the case and how by either searching the web or looking for yourself in SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, really - just join the `sys.procedures` and `sys.sql_modules` system catalog views to get the stored procedure definition.

This C# code illustrates this approach:

```
string connectionString = "server=YourServerName;Database=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

string query = @"SELECT m.definition 
                 FROM sys.procedures pr 
                 INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON pr.schema_id = s.schema_id
                 INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON pr.object_id = m.object_id 
                 WHERE pr.Name = @Name AND s.Name = @Schema;";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = "uspGetEmployeesTest2";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Schema", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = "HumanResources";

    conn.Open();
    object returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();

    if (returnValue != null)
    {
        string procedureDefinition = returnValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

This returns you everything - from the `CREATE PROCEDURE` to the last line of your procedure

Answer (score 0):

Sure. One way is to poke the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`. In a query editor you go like this:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE 
    ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'HumanResources' 
    AND ROUTINE_NAME = `uspGetEmployeesTest2`
```

Then you could refine the text you need even further by playing with `WHERE` and `LIKE`.